# Angular recursive template

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with an item template that recursively references itself but is not properly rendering out children beyond the first level. I've looked at several examples and it seems my example only differs in that my items are loaded by page via AJAX requests. Below I've linked to an example of the problem.

http://plnkr.co/edit/16wf1MS7vbk3qH8tcE7q?p=preview

```
<div my-directive></div>

<script id="myDirectiveTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
    <h4>
        My directive
    </h4>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>

<script id="itemTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
    <p>
        {{ item.title }}
    </p>
    <ul ng-if="item.children.length">
        <li ng-repeat="child in item.children" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

My directive:

```
angular.module("myApp")
.directive("myDirective", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {
var scope;

function loadPage() {
    // makes an ajax call here to get a page
    scope.items.push({ title: "Item 1", children: [] });
    scope.items.push({ title: "Item 2", children: [] });
    scope.items.push({
        title: "Item 3",
        children: [
            {
                title: "Child 1",
                children: []
            },
            {
                title: "Child 2",
                children: []
            }
        ]
    });
}

return {
    restrict: "A",
    templateUrl: "myDirectiveTemplate",

    controller: ["$scope", function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [];
        scope = $scope;
    }],

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        $timeout(function () {
            loadPage();
        });
    }
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tweaked logic bit and here is your updated [SAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/O3KmLWdF6Da0mPqWA9Gp?p=preview)

```
    <script id="myDirectiveTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
          <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
              {{item.title}}
              <div ng-if="item.children.length > 0" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </script>

   <script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTemplate">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.children">
          {{item.title}}
         <div ng-if="item.children.length > 0" ng-include="'itemTemplate'"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </script>
```

OR you can try below solution

```
<script id="myDirectiveTemplate1" type="text/ng-template">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'itemTemplateUpdated'"></li>
  </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="itemTemplateUpdated">
  {{item.title}}
  <ul ng-if="item.children.length > 0">
      <li ng-repeat="item in item.children" ng-include="'itemTemplateUpdated'">
      </li>
  </ul>
</script>
```

Comment: Well +1 for solving the problem for this particular example. My problem is that the "{{ item.title }}" example really represents a bunch of markup and Angular expressions that I don't want to have to repeat. Back to the drawing board I go.

Comment: In that case you can use third party JS like https://github.com/wix/angular-tree-control  Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/  . Till time I will try to minimize markup to enhance above given you sample.

Comment: I have updated my sample with less markup. This sample contains two solutions. Out of that one is old i.e. "Sample 1" and new solution is "Sample 2".

Comment: I ended up changing it from using a template with ng-include to making the item into its own directive. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/e4j0KbCq2G9tTZhzCwIx?p=preview

Comment: Good!! Make sense .